# Variable from Childe to Parent ASP

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am after a simple example/quick fix of passing a single value from dialog to asp parent page using JavaScript - if java script is best option that is!

I have made numerous attempts at doing this but failing with each effort so far.

lblVarSelectedDate.Text is the value i would like to post back to parent page to displayed as the lblVarChildSelectedDate value.

Below is part of Register.aspx page (PARENT)

```
    <table>
<tr>
      <td colspan="5" align="center"><asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text="Selected Date: "></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblVarChildSelectedDate" runat="server" ></asp:Label></td>
      <td colspan="1" align="center"><asp:Button ID="btnSelectDate" runat="server" Text="Date" /> </td>
</tr
<tr>
    <td><asp:Button ID="btOK" runat="server" Text="Ok" /> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is the VB behind register.aspx...

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


End Sub

Sub btnSelectDate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSelectDate.Click

    Dim Window As String
    Window = " window.open('selectdate.aspx', 'MsgWindow', 'width=500, height=500');"

    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType, "date", Window, true)


End Sub

Sub btnOk_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btOK.Click

End Sub
```

And now her is my child page selectdate.aspx..

```
    <table>
<tr>
    <td colspan="6"><asp:Calendar ID="calSelecter" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="SelectionChange"></asp:Calendar></td>

</tr>
<tr>
      <td colspan="6" align="center"><asp:Label ID="lblConsSelectedDate" runat="server" Text="Selected Date: "></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblVarSelectedDate" runat="server" ></asp:Label></td>
</tr
<tr>
    <td><asp:Button ID="btOK" runat="server" Text="Ok" /> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Her is the vb behind the child page.

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    calSelecter.SelectedDate = Date.Today
    lblVarSelectedDate.Text = Date.Today

End Sub

Sub btnOk_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btOK.Click

    ' .... on click post back to parent page lblVarSelectedDate.Text 

End Sub

Sub SelectionChange(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    lblVarSelectedDate.Text = calSelecter.SelectedDate

End Sub
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Are you hoping to do this without refreshing your parent page? "Post back to" usually implies a post back.

Comment: Yes without would be best as the parent page will be populated with other info!

Comment: You are going to need AJAX

Comment: You might want to post a variation of this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as there may be a better way of going about what you are looking to accomplish.

Comment: Is it not possible to simply using a value on the parent page from the child window then?

Comment: Yes, use JS window.opener see: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp  then you will just traverse the DOM as you normally would to the element.

Comment: So in my case can i do this ....

Window = " window.open('selecteddate.aspx', 'MsgWindow', 'width=500, height=500'); myWindow.opener.document.write(lblVarChildSelectedDate.Text = lblVarSelectedDate.Text );"

Comment: no, you need to use client-side scripting "JavaScript" to access the value of the control.  in .NET a Label will render as a <span> tag.  You need to be aware of the differences in your server-side programming and your client-side programming.

Answer (score 0):

If your application design allows it, and you feel up to trying it, I'd use a jQuery dialog for your child window rather than a separate browser window.  Then you could use jQuery to populate the field on your "parent" page from the selected date on the dialog box, without needing to post back.

In fact, depending on what you're ultimately trying to do, you might even find that the jQuery UI Datepicker widget meets your needs, and that you don't need any custom programming:

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

If it doesn't meet your needs, let me know in the comments and I'll fill this answer out with specific code for the jQuery dialog box solution.

Comment: If you opt for a jQuery date picker make sure that you append the widget inside the form element.  By default it will append the widget outside of the form and you will not get the posted back value.

Comment: How would includ the jquery in my asp page?